# Error in Maven building process of Spring MVC Showcase Example

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, maven-3

After that I have copy the Spring MVC Showcase example from a workspace to another workspace I have do the following thning:

1) Delete the repository directory from ./m2 folder
2) Within STS\Eclipse I have do a Maven Install of the project

So Maven begin to download the dependencies of the project but the build process end with the following error message in the stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] MvcAsyncTask cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:29.538s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 06 12:43:05 CET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/160M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile (default)     on project spring-mvc-showcase: Compiler errors :
[ERROR] error at import org.springframework.web.context.request.async.MvcAsyncTask;
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] /home/andrea/Documents/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-mvc-showcase/src/main    /java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/async/CallableController.java:11:0::0 The import org.springframework.web.context.request.async.MvcAsyncTask cannot be resolved
[ERROR] error at public @ResponseBody MvcAsyncTask<String>     callableWithCustomTimeoutHandling() {
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] /home/andrea/Documents/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-mvc-showcase/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/async/CallableController.java:64:0::0 MvcAsyncTask cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] error at return new MvcAsyncTask<String>(1000, callable);
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] /home/andrea/Documents/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/spring-mvc-showcase/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/async/CallableController.java:74:0::0 MvcAsyncTask cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the     following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

And seems that I have some problem in the following class: **org.springframework.samples.mvc.async.CallableController.java** because give me the following error:

**The import org.springframework.web.context.request.async.MvcAsyncTask cannot be resolved**

Why Maven do this? How can I solve?

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-mvc-showcase</artifactId>
<name>spring-mvc-showcase</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.1</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.30</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson JSON Processor -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Rome Atom+RSS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.rome</groupId>
        <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR 303 with Hibernate Validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Joda Time Library -->  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- File Upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<repositories>  
    <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
        <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
    <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
    <repository>
        <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>                
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/Abstract*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <junitArtifactName>junit:junit</junitArtifactName>
                <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- Have to use version 1.2 since version 1.3 does not appear to work with ITDs -->
            <version>1.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see MNG-2972) -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outxml>true</outxml>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </plugin>   
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thank you very much

Andrea

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml file

Comment: yes, I have edit the original post adding the content of pom.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Im not sure if the msising class should be in the spring-webmvc dependency youre already includign but it is worth trying this one out

Comment: mmm I have not to as you say me...at this time I have solved in the following way: I have first copy the project folder in the new workspace, then I have imported it in STS and then I have run a Maven Install and seems to work...but this is strange...sometimes Maven have strange behavior expecially within STS\Eclipse...